# Fluent Nhibernate - Collection name naming convention

Tags: nhibernate, collections, fluent-nhibernate, naming-conventions

Is it possible to set a naming convention for all collection of an entity even if I use the Access Strategy or not, so that all collection names are `{EnityName}s` instead of `{entityName}s` (because of Access.CamelCaseField(Prefix.Underscore) the first letter is lower)?

Or is there a way where I can tell NHibernate that it shall use the associationPath case insensitive in the `SetFetchMode` method?

This method is not case insensitive:

```
ICriteria SetFetchMode(string associationPath, FetchMode mode)
```

I try to build a type safe way of setting the `associationPath`

**EDIT:**

The associationPath is the name attribute of the collection.

```
<set access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="employees" table="TeamEmployee" mutable="true">
```

I want to define a naming convention for the name attribute.

**EDIT:**

I found something like this:

```
public class LowercaseCollectionNameConvention : IClassConvention
{
    public void Apply(IClassInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Collections. ...
    }
}
```

Does someone one know how to use this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the context of your question. If you are after a naming strategy for the relationship during mapping and schema generation then you need to do some sort of "Convention".

I recently blogged my conventions http://blog.zoolutions.se/post/2010/07/03/Inflector-e28093-renaming-utilities.aspx and http://blog.zoolutions.se/post/2010/07/05/All-my-current-Fluent-NHibernate-Conventions.aspx

If you could add some better description I'll be happy to extend my answer.

**EDIT** The following should get you pretty close if you copy the Inflektor class from my blog or any other location it can be found:

```
public class HasManyConvention : IHasManyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IOneToManyCollectionInstance instance)
    {
        instance.Cascade.SaveUpdate();
        instance.Inverse();
        string pluralized = Inflector.Pluralize(instance.ChildType.Name);
        instance.Name(pluralized.ToLower());
    }
}
```

Comment: is your code for defining a naming convention for the name of the collection of the hbmxml file? <set access="field.camelcase-underscore" cascade="save-update" inverse="true" lazy="true" name="employees" table="TeamEmployee" mutable="true"> I want a convention for the name attribute.